# Access to the Parent node in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I think it will be very hard for you to read the code but I'll try to do my best !

Here is my xaml code :

```
<TreeView x:Name="stateMachinesView"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          SelectedItemChanged="item_Selected"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          BorderThickness="0">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Create Thumbnail" 
                                      Click="MenuItemCreate_Click"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Style.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Source"
                                            Value="Resources\state.png"/>
                                </Style.Setters>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Item2}"
                                                 Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                                Value="Resources\state_init.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <Binding Path="Item1"/>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DockPanel>
            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                   Source="Resources\state_machine.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The item source of this is a `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, bool>>>`

Visually, I got something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Now, when I click on my `MenuItem` I got this code:

```
private void MenuItemCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string stateName =
        ((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Tuple<string, bool>).Item1;
}
```

Here I can access to **State1_1** with the code above, but now I would like to access to **SM1** the parent node !

I tried a lot of things, the closest (to the solution) was this:

```
DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as DependencyObject);
while (!(parent is TreeViewItem))
    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
```

But it doesn't work...

I am, too, thinking about a Template in XAML but im sure I can do it in the code-behind easily!

Comment: are you looking for a simple way to loop thru a Treeview..? if so I can paste a very simple example that you can use as a starter in your code behind..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContextMenus` are not on the same visual tree as the object they are used on. You have go up twice

1. You need to get up to the `ContextMenu`, there you can get the `TreeViewItem` from the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget`.
2. Now you can go up that tree to the parent `TreeViewItem`.

Of course it would be easier if you just have a reference to the parent in the data items themselves. Also you should not need to acces the `TreeViewItems` as you usually bind everything as necessarry.

Comment: ContextMenu.PlacementTarget returns a DockPanel in my code. If I try to cast it to TreeViewItem, I got null. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Have you used the immediate window (ctrl + D + ctrl + I)? This can be used to access you object and see the type using typeof(). Also, if you have a reference to the tree view as a member of the class you can use the SelectedItem property to obtain the node. Initially I was having issues with a tree view entirely in code, and then I was convinced to get it working with XAML data binding. It is well worth it. If you need a functional TreeView sample I can provide my code, although I did not use the context menu it may still help.

Comment: @AnthonyMason: You'll want to use 'at' notation (as i am addressing you now) if you talk to someone in a comment section on a post whose author is not the person you intend to talk to. Otherwise the person you intend to address is not notified.